# Can't access my Careers profile

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I was invited a while ago and accepted, but can't seem to login to it.

I just received an email telling me to update my profile ("Done anything interesting lately? Add it to your [Careers 2.0 profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/43572)!"), but when I click the link it's a 404, and when I click "my profile" it asks me to request a profile.

How do I get back on it?

Comment: What was the link pointing to?  (excluding any referral ids/hashes that might be in it)

Comment: @Jeff http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/43572

Answer (score 3):

You had two accounts... The reminder was for one, and you logged in to the other. I've merged them so you should be all set.